# GTK TextView - creating a static display format

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, gtkmm, gtktextview

I am trying to simulate a piece of hardware, and this hardware has a static ribbon display.

to do this, I'd like to use a TextView.  My display has 10 rows, with 25 columns.  So I figured that a TextView should be easy enough.

basically, I would like to be able to say *"insert/replace string S at row X, starting at column Y"*.  i may need to only update a specific row, or even a single column within a row.

I have not been successful at getting this to work though.  the best I have been able to do is to fill the TextView with 10 lines of 25 spaces when i create it, and then use the `get_iter_at_line_offset` to get the iterator of a line, and then push the new text onto that line.

but this will start appending text to the line, rather than replacing the existing one.

I need both row and column control (i.e. need to be able to set text at a specific (X,Y) coordinate).

I'm assuming this is somehow possible using marks.

Can anyone give me a quick example of how i can do this?  Unfortunately, there isn't a whole lot of documentation on this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't know what a static ribbon display is, but based on your description, I think a Gtk::DrawingArea based approach would be relatively straightforward and make it possible to control the look of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get an iter at a specific line, row X, and then use the iterator's `forward_chars()` method to move forward Y characters. Then delete the number of characters you are replacing, and finally insert the text you want to insert. You can do it all with iterators, I think - iterators are invalidated when you change the buffer, but when you delete text, one of your iterators is revalidated to point to the place where the text was.

Comment: would it be completely awful to simply maintain my GUI in memory, and then use set_text to do a basic wipe and refresh on the entire buffer when i want it changed?  basically perform all of my manipulations on a long char array (with newlines at every 25th index), and then push that via set_text?

Comment: Depends on how often you need to update the display. Perhaps best to just try it, and then optimize it later if it's too slow? Memory won't be a problem, most computers have at least 250 bytes of memory these days.

Comment: updates once a second.  i think i will go this route.  i like the idea of using cairo like unwind posted, but i have a deadline to meet for a beta test, so i will do it this way for now, and optimize it later, once i get time for phase 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targetting GTK+ 3.x, you should really look into using Cairo. Since you don't actually need a text buffer, it seems like overkill and a bit of a mis-alignment to use the GtkTextView.

Look at the very basic introduction on how to [draw with Cairo in GTK+](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html#id1485153). Then look at the [text-rendering Cairo APIs](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-text.html), that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Hey. Why just GTK+ 3.x. and not with GTK+ 2? I know there are quite a few changes here and there, but are there any performance improvements? Because from my experience, Cairo is awful for something like that.